# Is reactive extensions a part of .net framework, is it recommended to use

Tags: .net, reactive-programming

Is reactive extensions a part of .Net framework?

Please guide if it is worth spending time on it? I am already using observers and async patterns in my projects. What new it can bring for us?

I would be really grateful if someone can help with Some scenarios where it has been used in real world applications.